# Am I not using typeof() correctly here?

Tags: c++, stl, g++

My code looks like this

```
#define tr(c,i) for(typeof((c).begin() i = (c).begin(); i != (c).end(); i++)

...

typedef vector<long> vl;
vl numbers;

...

tr(numbers, j) { // this is line 95
    ...
}
```

The code looks okay to me, but not to my compiler! Mercilessly, I am given the following errors:

> code.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> code.cpp:95:9: error: specialization of ‘std::vector::iterator’ after instantiation
>
> code.cpp:95:9: error: expected primary-expression before ‘typeof’
>
> code.cpp:95:9: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘typeof’
>
> code.cpp:95:9: error: name lookup of ‘j’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping
>
> code.cpp:95:9: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your
>   code)
>
> code.cpp:95:9: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘j !=
>   numbers.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end with _Tp = long int, _Alloc =
>   std::allocator, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator =
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >, typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer =
>   long int*’

What am I missing here?

Comment: @DeadMG, I understand the general sentiment against macros. But what's the actual problem in this case? Apart from the risks associated with the fact that `c` is evaluated multiple times. And the non-portability of `typeof`.

Comment: what's typeof keyword?? first time seeing it..

Comment: If you're able to use C++11, look into `auto` and `decltype` rather than (Apparently) compiler extensions.

Comment: @codekiddy: It's a GCC extension to get the type of an expression. It's pretty much the same as `decltype` in C++11, although I suspect there will be some subtle differences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a missing parenthesis in the macro.

```
#define tr(c,i) for(typeof((c).begin() i = (c).begin(); i != (c).end(); i++)
                                      ^
                                 Need ) here
```

Try fixing that and see what errors you get.

Minor note 1: When iterating, use `++i` instead of `i++` as the former can often faster for iterators.

Minor note 2: `typeof` is a GCC specific extension. Your code will not compile on other compilers.

Comment: Yes. Missing parenthesis and braces can often cause very confusing errors because they cause the compiler to parse your code in a completely different way than you intended. Something we just have to live with I'm afraid :-)

Comment: @PeterAlexander: Or just use simpler code: `for (n : numbers) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: You can use `auto` or `decltype((c).begin())` instead in C++11.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm not going to suggest C++11 features until they are ubiquitous.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're missing a ')'

```
#define tr(c,i) for(typeof((c).begin()) i = (c).begin(); i != (c).end(); i++)
```